# Maven - Maven plugin doesn't execute when declared in a dependency

Tags: maven, plugins

I'm building a library for the main project and passed the whole day on how to invoke a plugin when the main project is built. This plugin is declared in the library's POM and I don't have control over the main project.

Main project POM:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>my_library</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

POM of the `my_library`:

```xml
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-file</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceFile>target/${project.artifactId}_${project.version}_noarch.jar
                            </sourceFile>
                            <destinationFile>bin/app.jar</destinationFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Nothing happens when I run:

```
mvn package
```

So there are two questions:

1. Is that possible to invoke that plugin when my library is included this way?
2. If yes, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First question: Why do you need copy-rename-maven-plugin? If you like to use your own library define a dependency? Can elaborate more what and how ? And also show log output etc. Which Maven version etc.